# BaasBox Upload an image from C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, baasbox

I am trying to upload a picture to BaasBox in C#/Xamarin. So far I only get Bad Request errors:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9000/file");
            request.ContentType = "Content-type: image/jpg";
            request.Method = "POST";
            string authInfo = "user:password";
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = pictureFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                var bytearray = ms.ToArray();

                Stream reqstr = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
                reqstr.Write(bytearray, 0, buffer.Length);

                WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine("Response: " + response);
            }
```

The documentation only says it is uploaded via post using parameter file?!

Comment: is your `authInfo` Base64String ? => http://stackoverflow.com/a/25852562/4610605

Comment: Yes, logging in works fine.

Comment: Maybe this can help you. I cannot see any problems in your code... https://github.com/OlexaLe/BaasBoxNetSDK

Comment: I know this already, but it does not contain any code for file up- or download.

Comment: Did you also check the official SDK ?