# C# Http Request with username

Tags: c#, http, post, request

Hello everyone I am currently working on a Post Method of my C# work. As the URL I am going to send request to requires username and password, I have it but I do not know how to include them in my code. How should I insert them into my code?

Here is my request:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="myboundary"
From: 12345678
To: 12345678
Password: my_Password
Username: my_UserName

--myboundary
Content-Type: application/smil
Content-ID: <abc.smil>
Content-Location: abc.smil
```

Here are my code:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://myurl.com");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/related; boundary = myboundary";
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
```

Comment: Can you share your current code? That will make it easier to help you out.

Comment: @ThePretendProgrammer yes I have just edited my questions with my code. I have just started it so it may not be a detailed one...

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852551/how-to-add-basic-authentication-header-to-webrequest) SO post looks like the answer to your question, assuming you intend to use basic username-password authentication.

Comment: @ThePretendProgrammer Thank you so much, can u please also check my requirements? I am new to C# so please I need some help.. Thanks!!